# az vim run-command invoke shell script with parameters

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I want to run a script using az cli invoke.

```
I_PASS_THIS_VAR=${1}
az vm run-command invoke     --command-id RunShellScript \
                                 --scripts '@foo.sh' \
                                 --parameters=${I_PASS_THIS_VAR} \
                                 -o tsv
```

where I pass $I_PASS_THIS_VAR and it is some string. Then the foo.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
PARAM=${1}
if [ ${PARAM} ]
then
    echo "export MY_PARAM=${PARAM}" >> "${HOME_DIR}/.bashrc"
fi
```

I does not work. The MY_PARAM equals nothing. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

To run the shell script in a Linux VM, the command should like this:

```
az vm run-command invoke -g group_name -n vm_name --command-id RunShellScript --scripts @run_command.sh --parameters param1
```

The shell script is in the place where you run the Azure CLI command. And the shell script for you will like this:

```
if [ $1 ]
then
        echo "export My_Param=$1" >> "/path/.bashrc"
fi
```

You can input the parameters in the Azure CLI command as the value of `--parameter` and quote them in the shell script like the above code. One point you should take care of is that the `path` in the above code should be an absolute path. For example, `/home/useraccount/.bashrc` and the `useraccount` is the user you want to export the environment variable.